# 'Notice: Undefined offset 1' when inserting values in multi assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, fgets

That's the code:

```
$myarray = ['asdf' => array(), 'zxcv' => array()];

    while (!feof($file))
    {
      $line = fgets($file);
      if (strpos($line, "mystring")
      {
            $temp = explode(" ", $line);
            $temp2 = explode(":", $temp[2]);
            if (array_key_exists('1', $temp2))
            {
                $myarray['asdf'][] = "1";
            }
      }
}
```

Problem occurs only when parsing a huge file (2mil+ lines). Dumping the array shows that the values are there (same "mystring" count gives me and Notepad++), but this notice looks like `array_key_exists()` returns false when it's not. Any ideas?

Brief explanation of my goal:
Lines in the file have the following structure - `blabla mystring blabla blabla`, up to 20 space delimiters. To be precise `mystring` is DHCPOFFER. In my case I'm trying to insert in the array the time when condition is met and line is added to the logfile (isc-dhcpd logfile). The blabla next to `mystring` is nn:nn:nn, which is a standart time pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`$temp2` is a list, not an associative array. You shouldn't use `array_key_exists`.

Since it's impossible that `explode` returns a sparse array, or associative array a simple `count($temp2)` should be enough.

---

You want use `array_key_exists` for associative arrays:

```
$arr = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "ipsum" => "lorem"
);
var_dump(array_key_exists("foo", $arr)); // true
var_dump(array_key_exists("bar", $arr)); // false
```

If your array is a list, then you can use `count`

```
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
var_dump(count($arr) > 2); // true, ok so we can do $arr[2];
var_dump(count($arr) > 5); // false, ok so we can't do $arr[5];
```

Comment: In PHP online documentation is clearly stated that `explode()` returns an array of strings.

Comment: Yep, so don't use `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Well, `array_key_exists` returns true if the given key or index is set in the array. I can't understand you :\

Comment: Even using your suggestion for `count()` I got the same results:
1046613 "mystring" matches during `fgets()`  
829011 "mystring" elements in the array

And no PHP errors in the log :\

Comment: Does your file contain strings like `foomystring`, `mystring,`, `mystring.` or `MyString`? That would totally explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Updated the question with additional case info.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, your array is not associative, `so array_key_exists()` won't return true if checking against a string.

In your code you are matching against `'1'`, which is a string. Shouldn't you use `1`, which is an integer ?

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I said `array_key_exists()` returns true if key or INDEX is in the array (we have an element with our number that is inserted). Which is valid as `isset($temp2[1])`. The problem is that whatever (array) function I'm using, the results are same. Looks like some lines are not read at all. While using `gawk` tool I don't face the problem and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found where is the problem. Let see the following code:

```
while (!feof($file))
{
  $line = fgets($file, 4096);
  $counters['linecount']++;
  for ($elem = 0; $elem < 4; $elem++)
  {
    if (strpos($line, $searchitem[$elem]) !== FALSE)
    {
      $line2 = preg_replace("/^ {2}(.*)$/", " ", $line);
      //or $line2 = str_replace("  ", " ", $line);
      //or $line2 = str_replace("\\t", " ", $line);
      $temp = explode(" ", $line2);
      $temp2 = explode(":", $temp[3]);
      if (isset($temp2[3]))
      {
        echo "blah";
      }
      else { die("<pre>" . print_r($temp) . "</pre>"); }
    }
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Nov [1] => [2] => 1 [3] => 00:00:02 [4] => xxx [5] => dhcpd: [6] => DHCPREQUEST [7] => for [8] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [9] => from [10] => xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [11] => via [12] => vlan1 )
```

It seems that first `explode()` function did not work well (my opinion), it puts empty string element where it shouldn't. For this reason we need change the second `explode()` function to read from 4th element (`$temp[3]`), but this f***s up other lines that were read, a lot earlier as number (my first doublespace line is #20266, but now is #29). Which means we need to set check conditions for lines with two spaces and/or `"\t"`s

Current state of the mind: Frustrated, I think some new "features" will pop soon :(